# I change .htaccess file and it show me blank page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want create a shortUrl for my web service and  i insert below code in .htaccess but when i request to open other page ,  web service can't render that page .

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?l=$1 [L]
```

This code change URL link to without get syntex for shortlink service and it was working great but when i have a request to other page browser show me blank page without any code an when i remove up code browser can render other page !!

I'm sorry for my poor english . 
Thanks for helping.

Comment: what do _you_ mean by `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)`?

Comment: @Ejay i don't have any idea .i copy this code from the opensource  project from here ( http://goo.gl/RqivgH ) . i don't have any familiar with htaccess .